# Copy all content from a branch to trunk with history using TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have this scenario:

1. A branch with my current work
2. A trunk without content

I need copy all content from 1 to 2 with all history from 1.
Is it possible? Is possible using svn commands to this. I want keep the work in branch and not move. Just copy.

Answer (score 1):

Using the copy command is simple:

[Tortiose svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html)

why do you need to copy all the history from the trunk? You already got the right in the trunk where it belongs.

Comment: My trunk was very deprecated. So, when I make a merge, we have many issues. Then, I remove all old content from trunk and now need get all content from branch to trunk. But, this reversal way is very hard to me. I tried copy making a branch assign to trunk but it's not possible too.

Comment: What do you mean your trunk was deprecated? Your trunk should be your main line of work and always be "ready to release" state, if you got deprecated stuff in your trunk you should clean it up and commit those changes.